# How to monitor the change of a process's working directory?

Tags: linux, inotify

I want to monitor the current working directory of an arbitrary process with a given PID under Linux.

My idea is to use inotify on the procfs. Every process has its own directory under /proc/PID and there is a symlink pointing to the actual working directory /proc/PID/cwd

I want to get notified when this symlink changes, but if I put a watch on the symlink it will start watching the directory the symlink points to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may as well use strace and watch it for making chdir() system calls - as those really are the only way to change the current working directory.

This is really a debugger-style requirement, and you're going to need to use debug interfaces to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this? From [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/inotify.7.html):

```
The following further bits can be specified in mask when calling
inotify_add_watch(2):

IN_DONT_FOLLOW (since Linux 2.6.15)
    Don't dereference pathname if it is a symbolic link.
```

Comment: I tried that one already, should have mentioned it in the question, sorry. It simply does nothing when I use this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can.  procfs is not a real file system, it is only generated on demand when you read from it.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm afraid of, but I'm open to other ideas to solve this.